# Make shortcuts to commands with arguments

Tags: shortcut

I am frequently using the same command and want some shortcuts.  How can I make shortcuts to `\color{blue}\textbf{some text}}`?

Comment: `\newcommand{\boldblue}[1]{{\color{blue}\textbf{#1}}}` and then `\boldblue{some text}`? This is quite a basic macro, you can learn more on https://www.learnlatex.org/en/lesson-06

Comment: `\newcommand{\boldblue}[1]{\textcolor{blue}{\textbf{#1}}}` feels more natural to me.

Comment: @Rmano There are cases where `\color` might produce undesired output, for instance if `\boldblue` appears at the beginning of a paragraph. Using `\textcolor` is much better.

Comment: @greg I know but the OP used it - maybe they need to put paragraphs there? :-;

Comment: Am now using `\textcolor` as instructed.